# calling one function to another everything works except one if-statement

Tags: c

When I'm calling searchIt() fucntion inside ch() fucntion everything works except it does not respond to 0 when I try to quit. If I call the ch() function I get prompt
printf("Itemnumber(0 to quit): "); and if I insert 0 the program does not react and continues to printf("change inventory: ");.

```
void ch(Shop a[], int n){
    
    while(1){
        int input;       
        const int i = searchIt(a,n);
        printf("change inventory: ");
        scanf("%d", &input);

        a[i].inv += input;
        if(a[i].inv<0){
            printf("balance is now 0!\n");
            a[i].inv= 0;  
        }
    }
    return;
}
int searchIt (Shop a[], int n){

    while(1){

        int itemN;
        printf("Itemnumber(0 to quit): ");
        scanf("%d", &itemN);
            if(itemN==0){
                break;
                }
                int count=0;
                for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
                    if(itemN==a[i].itemN){                                           
                        printf("%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\n", a[i].itemN, a[i].name, a[i].inv); 
                        return i;                         
                        break;                   
                    }                 
                }if(!count){
                    printf("Wrong item number!\n");                   
                }
    } return 0;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't react"? It does react. Since you wrote `if(itemN==0){ break; }` it breaks from that loop, gets to the end of searchIt, so searchIt returns, and then the computer is back at the next line in ch, which is `printf("change inventory: ");`

Comment: But it does not behave sameway as in searchit() function. It behaves just like when I enter any other number. But I understand what you mean, so it does break out but instead of going but to menu it moves to printf("change iventory: "); How do I change the code so it goes back to menu when I press 0?

Comment: After a function finishes, the computer goes to the next instruction after the function call. You understand this, yes? After `printf("hello");` (this is a function call) the computer goes to the next instruction after `printf("hello");`

Comment: I did write in pervious comment that I understood. I just said that it looks like it does not break out when I press 0 since it goes to print("change inventory": ); as usual. But I understand. I'm just trying to make it break out so it goes back to the menu.

Comment: `break` breaks out of one loop. Not every loop. The loop is the `while(1)` loop inside the function `searchIt`.

Comment: You could make it so searchIt returns -1, and then ch sees if the number is -1 and if it's -1 then it also breaks out of its loop.

Comment: I tried return itemN; and then added itemN  to cont int i. so it looks like const int i, itemN  = searchIt(a,n); and the if(itemN==0){ break} but now it deos not loop all the way it stops after I enter ivnentory

Comment: A function can only return one thing.

Comment: oh okej right, then I'm out of ideas:/

Comment: Do you mean return -1 instead of  0? if I cant pass itemN to ch() how does it know if it was -1? I mean I have to compare something like if(itemN==(-1)){break}, but if I cant have itemN then how. And also will I still be able to decrease inventory with -1.?

Comment: `if(itemN == 0) {return -1;}` for example

Answer (score 0):

1. (main issue) `searchIt()` now returns -1 if user selects 0, and `ch()` uses that to restart loop.  If you want to return from `ch()` in this case change the `continue` to either `break` or `return`.
2. Reverse engineered code to figure the structure of Shop, and how to drive it.  Added missing includes.  This should have been part of the initial question.
3. (minor) Removed `count` which was set and never changed.
4. (minor) Removed break after return as it doesn't do anything.
5. (minor, not fixed) If you swap the `a` and `n` arguments you can document the relation between the two variables with modern compilers.  For example `int searchIt(int n, Shop a[n])`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int inv;
    int itemN;
    char *name;
} Shop;

int searchIt(Shop a[], int n) {
    for(;;) {
        int itemN;
        printf("Itemnumber (0 to quit): ");
        scanf("%d", &itemN);
        if(itemN==0){
            break;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
            if(itemN==a[i].itemN){
                printf("%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\n", a[i].itemN, a[i].name, a[i].inv);
                return i;
            }
        }
        printf("Wrong item number!\n");
    }
    return -1;
}

void ch(Shop a[], int n){
    for(;;) {
        const int i = searchIt(a,n);
        if(i == -1)
            continue;

        int input;
        printf("change inventory: ");
        scanf("%d", &input);

        a[i].inv += input;
        if(a[i].inv<0){
            printf("balance is now 0!\n");
            a[i].inv= 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    Shop s[] = {
        {0, 1, "a"},
        {1, 2, "b"},
    };
    ch(s, sizeof s / sizeof *s);
}
```

and here is an example run:

```
Itemnumber (0 to quit): 0
Itemnumber (0 to quit): 1
1               a               0
change inventory: 1
Itemnumber (0 to quit): 1
1               a               1
change inventory: -2
balance is now 0!
```

Consider changing your design so the user interaction is separate from the search logic.  For example by moving `Itemnumber` promtp to `ch()` or a separate function that only deals with the menu.